# Unusual rounded corners markup

Tags: css, rounded-corners

I'm trying to build a simple layout with a box inside another, however, while the external box has all four corners rounded, the inner one has only those of the right side.

I'll add the basic markup I started with just to fullfill the SO requirements but it's much easier to see [everything in action](https://jsfiddle.net/8aobsjq3/):

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="left">
    <div class="placeholder">Placeholder</div>
  </div>
  <div id="main"></div>
</div>
```

The inner corners are not exactly rounded and although I know that the reason is because I didn't define any other borders for that element, if I do, in the end, I can't have all border **6px** thick in a smooth way (outer gets thickier on the left).

The closest approach I achieved was [this one](https://jsfiddle.net/8aobsjq3/2/), making both left borders, external and internal, **3px** to have the desired **6px** but the area near the corners are clearly thinner, which is not what I had in mind.

As an extra, more as curiosity, when I tried to round the left inner borders as well, I ended up messing everything, with a space closer to ther cornerrs. Why is this?

Comment: Is [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zwjyjzxa/) what you want?

Comment: Almost. The left side is perfect, even without that very subtle black border you can see on mine. But the right side, the top and bottom curves should be better visible, indicating that they're really curved. I guess that's because you made them **12px** instead of **20px** ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I'm not the biggest fan of relative/absolute positioning, using them in this case seemed to be what I needed to solve the problem:

```css
body {
    background-color: #000;
    margin: 35px 35px 35px 50px;
}

#wrapper {
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 20px;
 -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
        -moz-border-radius-topright: 20px;
     -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 20px;
            border-top-right-radius: 20px;
         border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;

    border: 6px solid #0A1818;
    margin-left: 20px;
    min-height: 500px; /* demo only */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

#left {
    -webkit-border-radius: 35px;
       -moz-border-radius: 35px;
            border-radius: 35px;

    background-color: #051113;
    border: 6px solid #0A1818;
    left: 35px;
    min-height: 500px; /* demo only */
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="left">

    <div class="placeholder">Placeholder</div>

</div>
    
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="main"></div>

</div>
```

I hope it helps someone in the future :)